# Google Maps api key options?

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3, ionic-framework, cordova-3

I am working on a Cordova application and intend to use google maps, as per my understanding and the ionic maps starter example. We use maps api key for web and load the maps.

Doubtful about

1- Since it will be packaged in apk so I cannot restrict the api key to a specific domain. This doesn't look so good in terms of security.

2- The app will be installed in devices and each of these will have the maps api key inside application, what if I have to change this api key in future?

If someone has already faced such challenges please suggest.

Thanks

Comment: Can you ask your question straightly, it is so confusing so that i can help you

Comment: Okay sorry if I couldn't make it clear. How to intgrate maps in a webapp ? Which type of google maps api key should be used.

Comment: I have been following as per the starter app here https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-starter-maps/blob/master/index.html   and when I go to the google maps api docs to read, first thing told is to get an api key. Thanks for taking time to understand the problem it would be nice if you provide some references. It's difficult to digest that you can use google maps APIs without key. I need to put markers and reverse geocode and other functions like calculating distance etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While Using cordova  you **don't** require any API key for google maps to show it in webview

**EDIT**

Just remove the API key field

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js key=AIzaSyB16sGmIekuGIvYOfNoW9T44377IU2d2Es&sensor=true"></script>
```

like this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
```

Comment: I just tried and it worked, this seems to be something interesting. Thank you

Comment: Now how will google restrict the number of API calls and track ? Is this really a feature? But thanks a lot.